# Throwing NullPointerException in the catch block

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am having problem understanding the following.
I have a class called TestClass20 which when I compile and run I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" MyException
        at TestClass20.m1(TestClass20.java:21)
        at TestClass20.main(TestClass20.java:17)
```

//TestClass20.java

```
class MyException extends IllegalArgumentException{}
public class TestClass20{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      TestClass20 tc = new TestClass20();
      try{
         tc.m1();
      }
      catch (MyException e){


         tc.m2(); // THIS IS LINE 11



      }
      finally{
           tc.m1();   // THIS IS LINE 17
      }
   }
   public void m1() throws MyException{
      throw new MyException();   //THIS IS LINE 21
   }
   public void m2() throws RuntimeException{
      throw new NullPointerException();
   }
}
```

The problem I have is why is line 11 not throwing any NullPointerException. Line 11 is calling m2() method which is throwing a new NullPointerException, so I would expect it to throw NullPointerException. The output I am expecting should be:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  // Exception that should have been thrown by line 11
```

Then

```
Exception in thread "main" MyException  // Exception thrown by line 17.
```

In summary:
line 11 should have thrown NullPointerException first and then line 17 throws MyException

If I change the code slightly to this:

//TestClass21.java

```
class MyException extends IllegalArgumentException{}
public class TestClass21{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      TestClass21 tc = new TestClass21();


         tc.m2(); //LINE 7




   }
   public void m1() throws MyException{
      throw new MyException();
   }
   public void m2() throws RuntimeException{
      throw new NullPointerException();
   }
}
```

Then I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at TestClass21.m2(TestClass21.java:17)
        at TestClass21.main(TestClass21.java:7)
```

So why did NullPointerException prints in TestClass21.java but it did not print in TestClass20.java? Is it not possible to print exception (NullPointerException or any other RuntimeException) in the catch block?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have `tc.m1(); ` in finally block so MyException is thrown.

Comment: Why did you expect something different?  The `finally` block is *always* executed.  Would be even if no exception at all were thrown in the `try` range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `tc.m1();` in finally block so MyException is thrown.

Finally always gets executed so the last exception is the one thrown at finally. And yes `NullPointerException` is also thrown but it is suppressed by the `MyException` in the finally block.

Remove the `tc.m1();` from the finally block and you will see your `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thanks Subir. This seems to answer my question although I don't quite understand why NullPointerException is getting suppressed by the MyException

Comment: The simple answer is that it's because only one exception can exit the try-catch-finally block. And by definition it's the one thrown by `finally`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's how you can achieve what you want.

```
class MyException extends IllegalArgumentException{}
public class TestClass20{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      TestClass20 tc = new TestClass20();
      try{
         tc.m2();
      }
      catch (NullPointerException e){

       e.printStackTrace();

      }
      finally{
           tc.m1();
      }
   }
   public void m1() throws MyException{
      throw new MyException();
   }
   public void m2() throws NullPointerException{
      throw new NullPointerException();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 introduced a way to deal with situations like this, you can use the `addSuppressed()` method of `Throwable` to signal that your clean-up (that you'd put in a finally block) didn't finish normally.

```
    try {
        Exception e1 = null;
        try {
            throw new Exception( "original" );
        }  catch( Exception ex ) {
            e1 = ex;
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                throw new Exception( "from finally");
            } catch( Exception e2) {
                if (e1 != null)
                    e1.addSuppressed( e2 );
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
        for (Throwable t : ex.getSuppressed()) {
            System.out.println( "Suppressed: "+t.getMessage() );
        }
    }
```

The try-with-resources construct introduced in Java 7 works in a similar way too.